# In google app engine launcher, can you create a new project out of nothing?

Tags: google-app-engine

I installed Google App Engine Launcher on Windows 10. While I was trying to understand the mechanics of how to create a new project, I notice something very strange.  I make a new folder on the desktop, but don't make any app.yaml or main.py file.  So it is an empty folder. Then I create a new project using the Launcher using this folder as the parent folder.  I thought it wouldn't work. Surprisingly, the Launcher succeeds in making a new project. When I run and browse it, it shows "Hello World!".

How to explain this?!

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No. You need at least `app.yaml` file.

GAE is a collection of servers and `app.yaml` is used to configure them by providing specific instructions the platform understands.

Launcher is desktop application that emulates GAE platform and when you create project you need to point the Launcher to this file. If you don't, or if you delete `app.yaml` the project will become invalid.

You also need one more file to actually do anything, so minimal  configuration would looks something like this:

```
application: my-project
version: 1
runtime: python27
threadsafe: true
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: some-file.html
  upload: static/some-file\.html
```

To learn more you can start [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs) (:

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, you can create.**

You can create a **GAE Project** having nothing in that folder. You don't need to place or create files to create a new GAE Project. At the same time, @Sasxa is also right. GAE Projects invalid without app.yaml file.

**Behind the Scene**

So, when you create a new project using GAE Launcher, it creates all the necessary files for you which returns Hello World if you navigate to that Main Handler in browser.

> If you create new project using GAE Launcher, it creates all the necessary files to run a **template project** in that **parent directory**. You need to modify the project according to your needs.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. I misunderstood at the beginning.

Comment: Welcome. If your doubt is clarified, accept it as answer :)